# Installing dotnetnuke module install fails with 404

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

Im doing some dev work on a dnn module. I was able to build and install a package on my installation of DNN once. I made some changes and wanted to uninstall and reinstall it. Uninstalling went fine. Installing the module again failed by throwing a 404 on the install popup window as soon as i upload the new module zip. I dont see anything logged in the event viewer. Anyone know what can cause this?

Im running DNN 6.2.4

UPDATE: adding more info

the url its 404ing on is: "/Host/Extensions/tabid/36/ctl/Install/rtab/36/portalid/0/Default.aspx?popUp=true"

Im sure this is something unique to my module. I tried installing other modules and they worked fine.

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hitting F12 in your browser to load the Developer console and see if you can find what the URL is that is 404'ng, that'll make tracking down the issue easier.

Update: Since it appears to be the old "max upload size" issue check out this video for how to fix that part

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library/Viewer/Video/383/View/Details/How-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-DotNetNuke-6.aspx

Comment: Thanks Chris. Btw Im using your compiled module VS template for this project.

the url its 404ing on is: "/Host/Extensions/tabid/36/ctl/Install/rtab/36/portalid/0/Default.aspx?popUp=true

Comment: I would start by checking your .DNN file, make sure that it doesn't have any references to files that aren't in the ZIP file. Are you installing the SOURCE or INSTALL version of the module?

Comment: Im using the INSTALL package. It looks like everything that is being referenced is in the zip package. I did add a type='config' component to the .dnn config so that might be buggy. i'll try pulling out that. I noticed that within the Resources.zip achieve that a .dnn file gets put in there too. should that be there? Thanks!

Comment: I tried going into the package after its been built and deleting the Resources zip. That seems to get rid of the 404. Now I just need to find out why. Maybe its something in the Resources.zip that causing this?

Comment: Trying another build I assume doesn't help?

Comment: You might check to see if the web.config changes were removed when you uninstalled

Comment: I think I just figured it out. I went into the build script and removed the images dir include. I have a image directory of 46MB (alot of hi res images). That seems to allow it to go though. So I think this may be a issue with the webserver not allowing uploads that large? or its timing out? Is that configurable?

Comment: Updated the answer with a link